# Openlayers 4 DragBox not working on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, openlayers

I created a simple map with Openlayers 4, disabled every interaction on it and added a DragBox interaction.

```
map.getInteractions().forEach(function(int) {
    int.setActive(false);
});
var dragBox = new ol.interaction.DragBox();
dragBox.on('boxend', function() {
    // manage selection
});
dragBox.on('boxstart', function() {
    // clear previous selection
});
map.addInteraction(dragBox);
```

The dragbox works perfectly in Chrome on my PC, but the event 'boxstart' is never thrown in Chrome on my Android device.
Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance,
Marco